# Pythagoras in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, distance

Has anyone got any idea how to write pythagoras in a SQL script which then will be linked to a column in a table etc, the formula I'm trying to using is:-

```
(SQRT(MY_Y_AXIS-Y_AXIS^2)+(MY_X_AXIS-X_AXIS^2)
```

In all honesty I'm on my second day of using SQL and my previous task was just getting a sequence to work on my ID so if you can be rather dummed down with what to enter that would be great.

Comment: You look close - I think you just have parens in the wrong places.

Comment: I don't think that the ^ operator can be used for exponentiation in SQL. Simply multiply using *. And you are missing the parentheses around the differences. And also the square root should have parentheses enclosing the whole rest.

Comment: You can use `pow()` or `power()` instead of `^`.

Comment: my guess is that pow() is slower than the multiplication of the difference by itself - just a guess

Comment: @Walter Tross: measure it then :-)

Comment: @zerkms: did so, pow(...,2) is 10 to 15% faster on my MySQL 5.5 - not what I expected. Fine

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
SQRT( POW(MY_Y_AXIS - Y_AXIS, 2) + POW(MY_X_AXIS-X_AXIS, 2) )
```

Comment: 1. Check parentheses 2. Check `SELECT 4 ^ 3` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26564

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pythagoras theorem to find the minimum distance between 2 lat lon point tables in PostgreSQL.

```
create table if not exists public.test_pyth1 (
row_id serial,
lat float,
lon float);

create table if not exists public.test_pyth2 (
row_id serial,
lat float,
lon float
);

insert into public.test_pyth1 (lat, lon) values (1, 1);
insert into public.test_pyth1 (lat, lon) values (0, 2);
insert into public.test_pyth1 (lat, lon) values (1, 3);

insert into public.test_pyth2 (lat, lon) values (2, 1);
insert into public.test_pyth2 (lat, lon) values (2, 2);
insert into public.test_pyth2 (lat, lon) values (2, 3);

with min_distance as (
    select  buss_stop.row_id bid, MIN(POWER(buss_stop.lat-t.lat, 2) + 
POWER(buss_stop.lon-t.lon, 2)) mdistance
    from public.test_pyth1 buss_stop
    cross join public.test_pyth2 t
    group by buss_stop.row_id
),
distances as (
    select  buss_stop.row_id bid, t.row_id sid, POWER(buss_stop.lat-t.lat, 2) + 
POWER(buss_stop.lon-t.lon, 2) distance
    from public.test_pyth1 buss_stop
    cross join public.test_pyth2 t
) 
select * 
from distances d 
join min_distance md 
using(bid)
where md.mdistance = d.distance;
```